# How to determine whether content returned by .NET HttpClient is Gzipped?

Tags: c#, .net, gzip, dotnet-httpclient

I have a requirement to download some content from a remote URL and then also determine whether the content was compressed (Gzip or Deflate).

My issue is that when you allow the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient) to perform [automatic decompression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.automaticdecompression.aspx) then it doesn't return any value in the `response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding` property. If you *don't* enable automatic decompression then it does return the correct value for `ContentEncoding` but then you are left with a Gzipped document that hasn't been decompressed, which is not useful.

Take the following code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)");

    using (var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://www.twitter.com")))
    {
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(message))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string encoding = String.Join(",", response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding);

                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the `HttpClientHandler` is set to use `AutomaticDecompression` then the value in content is successfully requested as GZip and then decompressed correctly. But the `ContentEncoding` value in the response headers collection is empty.

If I remove the line:

```
AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
```

then I do get the correct `ContentEncoding` value ("gzip") returned, but then the document is returned in it's raw compressed format, which is no good.

So is there any way to get content that may sometimes (but not always) be GZipped and automatically decompress it when it is, but then know afterward whether it was originally sent as Gzip?

Comment: have you tried getting the raw header value instead of the computed property?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yep, it's also empty. I think the computed value just returns the value in the Headers collection.

Answer (score 7):

Not a full answer, but I peeked through the source code of `HttpClient` and that led me to the code of the underlying `HttpResponse`. In there, you find this nugget:

```
  if ((decompressionMethod & DecompressionMethods.GZip) != DecompressionMethods.None && str.IndexOf("gzip", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != -1)
  {
    this.m_ConnectStream = (Stream) new GZipWrapperStream(this.m_ConnectStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    this.m_ContentLength = -1L;
    this.m_HttpResponseHeaders["Content-Encoding"] = (string) null;
  }
```

As you can see, on the last line, they're removing that header altogether. I'm not entirely sure *why* that's what they decided to do, but it is what it is.

I guess your options are to either Unzip it yourself, or to make two requests (both of which aren't great options).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting - so it is deliberate. At least I know I'm not missing something!

Comment: If you are looking for the decompress yourself solution, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/765318/3866548) I found someone who did it.

Comment: They probably did this so that it wouldn't confuse the consumer that it had to decompress it again